# What do the centaurs in the Forbidden Forest eat?

Tags: harry-potter, magical-creatures, centaurs

Though I can't find any proof of this, I would assume that they are too proud to be carnivorous.  However, I also can't find anything about them eating any herbs or fruit from the Forbidden Forest.

Does anyone know what they eat?

Comment: They eat students who wander into the forest. Or at least I'm sure that's what the rumor is around Hogwarts.

Comment: I don't have the book but I would guess that *Fantastic Beasts And Where To Find Them* has a note on centaurs' diet.

Comment: Given that they're archers one might *suppose* they hunt animals for food

Comment: They eat UMBRIDGEs

Comment: yes ofc how did i not think of that :P

Comment: They lived on [treacle](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Page%3ALewis_Carroll_-_Alice's_Adventures_in_Wonderland.djvu/126).

Comment: I'm baffled by the premise; why would pride imply vegetarianism?

Comment: they consider themselves related to the rest of the animal kingdom

Comment: maybe? thats what i was aiming for

Comment: They consider humans to be lesser beings: "Our intelligence, thankfully, far outstrips your own."  I'm sure the same applies to animals.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## We don’t know - but it would be something found in the forests.

It’s never mentioned, either in the seven books or *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*, what centaurs eat. The only way we can narrow the possibilities down is that centaurs live in forests, so it’d have to be something (whether plant, animal, or both) that exists in the forests they live in.

> “The centaur is forest-dwelling. Centaurs are believed to have originated in Greece, though there are now centaur communities in many parts of Europe. Wizarding authorities in each of the countries where centaurs are found have allocated areas where the centaurs will not be troubled by Muggles; however, centaurs stand in little need of wizard protection, having their own means of hiding from humans.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*</sup></sub>

However, there’s nothing that implies whether they’re carnivores, herbivores, or omnivores. Their lifestyle could indicate either. They respect nature, which could imply that they’re herbivores, but there are many cultures that respect nature but also eat meat. They’re skilled at archery, which could imply they hunt for food, but it could also be a method of defense - when we see them use their archery skills it’s in combat or to protect themselves from something they perceive as a threat.

Answer (score -3):

### **Philosopher's Stone Chapter 15**

> “That is because it is a monstrous thing, to slay a  unicorn,” said
>   Firenze. “Only one who has nothing to  lose, and everything to gain,
>   would commit such a  crime. The blood of a unicorn will keep you
>   alive, even  if you are an inch from death, but at a terrible price. 
>   **You have slain something pure and defenseless to  save yourself**, and
>   you will have but a half-life, a  cursed life, from the moment the
>   blood touches your  lips.”

This quote from a centaur (especially the part that I bolded) can easily imply that they would look askance at killing animals for food. If that is the case then they are presumably herbivores.

Elsewhere, the centaurs confirm that it is not only unicorns that they don't kill, rather they don't kill anything innocent:

### Order of the Phoenix Chapter 30

> “Nevertheless,” said Magorian calmly, “the slaughter  of foals is a
>   terrible crime... **We do not touch the  innocent**.

Comment: i disagree, they're only talking about unicorns here man, they might view those as pure and defenseless but rabbits or the like could be completely different situation

Comment: this quote is also implying that humans dont kill unicorns but they still eat beef and chicken dont /hey?

Comment: The unicorn has been a symbol of purity for a long time killing one of them may be regarded as a special case, were killing a rabbit or a deer might not. But we have no proof either way, but the quote about unicorns as pure and defenceless does not prove it.

Comment: yes thank you thats what im trying to get at

Comment: At best this answer confirms that they *don't eat unicorn*.

Comment: @padfoot Why wouldn't the reason of "pure and defenseless" apply to other creatures as well? Also, see the edit where I added a quote that shows that they don't kill anything innocent.

Comment: @Sarriesfan As per my edit they also don't kill any foals because they are innocent.

Comment: @Valorum See above.

Comment: ok now you have proved they wont hurt Children

Comment: they can view that since other animals have adapted to being hunted they are no longer defenseless since they know when to run away, whereas unicorns were never hunted.

Comment: @padfoot They won't hurt children because children are innocent. Why is a rabbit less innocent than a child?

Comment: they wont hurt a young rabbit

Comment: @Alex - Because rabbits aren't intelligent

Comment: @Valorum Wouldn't that make them more innocent?

Comment: @Alex - Not really. A beast in the field is neither innocent nor virtuous. It's just a beast.

Comment: @Valorum Then why are foals innocent?

Comment: Because to centaurs foals and children as synonyms they use it to refer to the young of intellegent spieces theirs and humans. They  may also have a special place in their heart for other equines foals, but that does not prove they are vegetarians.

Comment: @Alex - Because they consider **human children and centaur children** to be equally innocent.